# Failed to load some modules gnu/linux

Tags: linux

I'vd a problem with loading modules.
Booting gives the this error:

```
     UNIT                         LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● systemd-modules-load.service loaded failed failed Load Kernel Modules

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

1 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
lucas@debian8-1:~$ 
ucas@debian8-1:~$ systemctl --failed
  UNIT                         LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● systemd-modules-load.service loaded failed failed Load Kernel Modules

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

1 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
lucas@debian8-1:~$ systemdctl status systemd-modules-load.service
bash: systemdctl: command not found
lucas@debian8-1:~$ systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service
● systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2015-06-23 12:53:00 CEST; 11min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
           man:modules-load.d(5)
  Process: 409 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 409 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Always the same error when booting. After a period of time, (Graphical User Interface) the mouse click no longer operates, also text input isn't possible. 
I had no access to the system at all, even crt alt F1 stopped working, also text input was no't possible. so reinstall was the only option.
Maybe there is a connection with this two errors.

I've reinstalled Debian 8 several times. Still, both errors stay.

Answer (score 1):

To get a complete log from the service, you can also use
journalctl -u systemd-modules-load.service

So presumably you have something in /etc/modules (or possibly
/etc/modules-load.d/) which refers to a nonexisting or broken module?

Removing it from /etc/modules will solve your issue.

:D